# Regex. Не выполнять условие, если подстрока — в кавычках

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

**Выполняется на js**

У меня есть **рег. выражение** `\/\*.*\*\/`, оно выполняет функцию поиска и **замены** программных **комментариев**. Но как сделать, **чтобы не срабатывало**, **если** **комментарий** находится **в кавычках**?

Comment: А вот бы увидеть исходную строку с которой проблема и кусок кода где регулярка чтобы понять что вы хотите сделать и какие исходные данные вызывают проблему

Comment: @RifmaMan строка с проблемой: `"/*комментарий*/"`

Comment: Надо чтобы если в кавычках, то не заменялось

Comment: Значит нужно сделать условие на проверку перед выполнение регулярки, что-то типа indexOf

Comment: @RifmaMan а если таких подстрок сто?

Comment: В смысле они все в 1 строке и ошибочные и нет?

Comment: @RifmaMan ну да

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать такой костыль: Сначала найти и убрать все строки на ключевое слово, которое вряд ли где-то еще встретится, убрать комментарии, потом по этому же слову вернуть все строки на место.

```js
let str = `let str = "/*bubu*/"; /* Нужно удалить только меня */ \nlet moo = 'moo /* but kuku */ and not dudu'`;

console.log( str );
console.log( replaceComments(str) );

function replaceComments(str){
  let strings = [];
  let i = -1;
  str = str
    .replace(/(["'`]).*?\1/g, function(a){
      strings.push(a);
      return 'bubukukududu007';
    })
    .replace(/\/*\*.*?\*\//g, "")
    .replace(/bubukukududu007/g, function(){
      i++;
      return strings[i];
    });
  return str;
}
```

Comment: С одной стороны, Ваше решение мне подходит, а с другой, я думаю, можно как-то обойтись без костылей

Comment: я о том же ) Понятия не имею как

Comment: **Не в тему** *Извините меня, я сижу с мобильного приложения сайта и решил обновить свой послкдний комментарий здесь. После обновления комментария у меня высветилось два моих одинаковых комментария; Я решил удалить двойника комментария, удалил , а потом оказалось , что это был ваш :(*

Comment: **Не в тему** *Вы не умеете удалять комментарии. Это я сам - и ушел думать))) Но всё равно кажется без костылей, одной регуляркой - никак*

Comment: **Не в тему** *А я уж перепугался, что я ваш удалил*

Answer (score 0):

С тех пор как задали вопрос регулярки получили развитие.

Теперь можно решить данную проблему одной регуляркой.

```js
let str = `let str = "/*bubu*/"; /* Нужно удалить только меня */ \nlet moo = 'moo /* but kuku */ and not dudu'`
const re = /(?<!['".*])\/\*.*\*\/(?!.*['"])/g
str = str.replace(re, '')
console.log(str)
```